# SVN cleanup directory not empty

Tags: svn

Im using the new SVN cleaup parameter to remove all the unversioned files

```
svn cleanup --remove-unversioned --remove-ignored
```

But then im constantly running into the error

> "svn: E720145: Can't remove directory ...\obj': The directory is not
>   empty. "

It will eventually remove all those folders after running the same command for like 10 times which means svn is able to delete those folders, not a permission issue.

Is there a way to fix this?